# Issue with SQL Script - Duplication

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL Script designed to pull data from multiple tables in a database. In principle this is working however I am looking to add the following behaviour:
A CASE WHEN Scenario where the a course title is checked against 3 possible options. If it is present in the title then it checks another database and finds the TOP 1 AssessorID (sorted by DESC End Date) that has a specific AssessorType. The idea being this type is the assessor for that type of course. If it doesn't exist in the 3 possible options it should just pull Assessor Type A against that course. Typically there could be 4 courses against 1 learner 3 could be for assessor type E or F and 1 for type A.

The script produces results however what happens is that it creates a duplicate row for each relevant course aka

Learner A -- Course A -- AssessorType A

Learner A -- Course B -- AssessorType E

What I'm looking to achieve is 1 line for 1 course but the correct single assessortype for that course based on the case when.

Here is the full script that is being run

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
                  TOP (100) PERCENT TRAINEE.LLWR_LEARN_ID AS MISLearnerID, 
                  REPLACE(TRAINEE.FIRSTNAME, ' ', '.')+REPLACE(TRAINEE.LASTNAME,' ','') AS UserID, 
                  TRAINEE.FIRSTNAME AS Forename, 
                  TRAINEE.LASTNAME AS Surname, 
                  TRAINEE.ADDRESS1 AS HomeAddressLine1, 
                  TRAINEE.LLWR_LEARN_ID AS StudentID, 
                  TRAINEE.ADDRESS2 AS HomeAddressLocality, 
                  TRAINEE.POSTTOWN AS HomeAddressTown, 
                  TRAINEE.COUNTY AS HomeAddressCounty, 
                  TRAINEE.UNIQUELEARNERNUMBER AS ULN, 
                  TRAINEE.POSTCODE AS HomeAddressPostCode, 
                  TRAINEEPOT2.LLWR_DISABLE2 AS LDisability,

                  CASE WHEN TRAINEEPOT2.LLWR_NUM_STRT = '1' THEN 'Entry Level 1' 
                  WHEN TRAINEEPOT2.LLWR_NUM_STRT = '1' THEN 'Entry Level 1' 
                  WHEN TRAINEEPOT2.LLWR_NUM_STRT = '2' THEN 'Entry Level 2' 
                  WHEN TRAINEEPOT2.LLWR_NUM_STRT = '3' THEN 'Entry Level 3' 
                  WHEN TRAINEEPOT2.LLWR_NUM_STRT = '5' THEN 'Level 1' 
                  WHEN TRAINEEPOT2.LLWR_NUM_STRT = 'D' THEN 'Level 2'
                  WHEN TRAINEEPOT2.LLWR_NUM_STRT = 'F' THEN 'Level 3' 
                  END AS InitialAssessmentNumeracy, 

                  CASE WHEN TRAINEEPOT2.LLWR_LITY_SRT = '1' THEN 'Entry Level 1' 
                  WHEN TRAINEEPOT2.LLWR_LITY_SRT = '2' THEN 'Entry Level 2' 
                  WHEN TRAINEEPOT2.LLWR_LITY_SRT = '3' THEN 'Entry Level 3' 
                  WHEN TRAINEEPOT2.LLWR_LITY_SRT = '5' THEN 'Level 1' 
                  WHEN TRAINEEPOT2.LLWR_LITY_SRT = 'D' THEN 'Level 2' 
                  WHEN TRAINEEPOT2.LLWR_LITY_SRT = 'F' THEN 'Level 3' 
                  END AS InitialAssessmentLiteracy, 

                  CASE WHEN TRAINEEINFO.U_DIGLIT = 'E1' THEN 'Entry Level 1' 
                  WHEN TRAINEEINFO.U_DIGLIT = 'E2' THEN 'Entry Level 2' 
                  WHEN TRAINEEINFO.U_DIGLIT = 'E3' THEN 'Entry Level 3' 
                  WHEN TRAINEEINFO.U_DIGLIT = 'L1' THEN 'Level 1' 
                  WHEN TRAINEEINFO.U_DIGLIT = 'L2' THEN 'Level 2' 
                  WHEN TRAINEEINFO.U_DIGLIT = 'L3' THEN 'Level 3' 
                  WHEN TRAINEEINFO.U_DIGLIT = 'na' THEN 'Not Applicable' 
                  END AS InitialAssessmentICT,

                  TRAINEE.EMAIL, TRAINEE.TELEPHONE AS TelNum, 
                  TRAINEE.DOB, 
                  TRAINEE.NINUMBER AS NationalInsuranceNo,
                      (SELECT     TOP (1) LONGSTRING
                        FROM          LOOKUP
                        WHERE      
                        (TABLENAME = 'TRAINEE') AND (FIELDNAME = 'GENDER') AND (SHORTSTRING = TRAINEE.GENDER)) AS Sex, 
                        TRAINEE.MOBILE, 
                  TREMPLOYER.EMPLOYERID AS MISEmployerID, 
                  TRAINEE_LLWR_ACT.LAIM_REF AS [Courses/Course/LadCode], 
                  TRAINEE_LLWR_ACT.TITLE_LA AS [Courses/Course/CourseName], 
                  TRAINEE_LLWR_ACT.EENDDATE AS [Courses/Course/CourseEndDate], 
                  TRAINEEPOT.STARTDATE AS [Courses/Course/CourseStartDate], 
                  TRAINEE_LLWR_ACT.TERMDATE AS [Courses/Course/ActualEndDate], TRAINEE_LLWR_ACT.REGNUMBER AS [Courses/Course/RegistrationNumber],

                  CASE WHEN TRAINEE_LLWR_ACT.TITLE_LA IN ('%CG COMM%','%CG AON%','%CG DIG LIT%') THEN

                    (SELECT TOP (1) TRASSESSOR.ASSESSORID
                        FROM TRAINEE INNER JOIN
                            TRASSESSOR ON TRAINEE.TRAINEEID = TRASSESSOR.TRAINEEID
                        WHERE (TRASSESSOR.ASSESSORTYPE = 'E' OR TRASSESSOR.ASSESSORTYPE = 'F') AND (TRASSESSOR.TRAINEEID = TRAINEE.TRAINEEID)
                        ORDER BY TRASSESSOR.ENDDATE DESC)
                        ELSE TRASSESSOR.ASSESSORID END AS [Courses/Course/MISAssessorID],

                  CASE WHEN TRAINEE_LLWR_ACT.COMPSTAT = 1 THEN 'IT' 
                  WHEN TRAINEE_LLWR_ACT.COMPSTAT = 2 THEN 'CM' 
                  WHEN TRAINEE_LLWR_ACT.COMPSTAT = 3 THEN 'EL' 
                  WHEN TRAINEE_LLWR_ACT.COMPSTAT = 4 THEN 'TR' 
                  WHEN TRAINEE_LLWR_ACT.COMPSTAT = 5 THEN 'TS' 
                  WHEN TRAINEE_LLWR_ACT.COMPSTAT = 6 THEN 'EL' END AS [Courses/Course/Status]

FROM         TRAINEE INNER JOIN
                  TREMPLOYER ON TRAINEE.TRAINEEID = TREMPLOYER.TRAINEEID INNER JOIN
                  TRAINEE_LLWR_ACT ON TRAINEE.TRAINEEID = TRAINEE_LLWR_ACT.TRAINEEID INNER JOIN
                  TRASSESSOR ON TRAINEE.TRAINEEID = TRASSESSOR.TRAINEEID INNER JOIN
                  TRAINEEINFO ON TRAINEE.TRAINEEID = TRAINEEINFO.TRAINEEID INNER JOIN
                  TRAINEEPOT ON TRAINEE.TRAINEEID = TRAINEEPOT.TRAINEEID INNER JOIN
                  TRAINEEPOT2 ON TRAINEE.TRAINEEID = TRAINEEPOT2.TRAINEEID 

WHERE     (TRAINEEINFO.U_E_PORTFOLIO = 'Yes') AND (TRAINEE.ADMINCENTREID = '0003') AND 
                  (TRAINEE_LLWR_ACT.DELIVERY = '09' OR
                  TRAINEE_LLWR_ACT.DELIVERY = '03' OR
                  TRAINEE_LLWR_ACT.DELIVERY = '02') AND (TRASSESSOR.ENDDATE =
                      (SELECT     MAX(ENDDATE) AS Expr1
                        FROM          TRASSESSOR AS TRASSESSOR_1
                        WHERE      (TRAINEE.TRAINEEID = TRAINEEID))) AND
                      ((SELECT     TOP (1) EMPLOYERID
                          FROM         TREMPLOYER AS TREMPLOYER_1
                          WHERE     (TRAINEEID = TRAINEE.TRAINEEID)
                          ORDER BY STARTDATE DESC) = TREMPLOYER.EMPLOYERID) 
ORDER BY surname
```

The particular CASE WHEN in question here is:

```
CASE WHEN TRAINEE_LLWR_ACT.TITLE_LA IN ('%CG COMM%','%CG AON%','%CG DIG LIT%') THEN

                    (SELECT TOP (1) TRASSESSOR.ASSESSORID
                        FROM TRAINEE INNER JOIN
                            TRASSESSOR ON TRAINEE.TRAINEEID = TRASSESSOR.TRAINEEID
                        WHERE (TRASSESSOR.ASSESSORTYPE = 'E' OR TRASSESSOR.ASSESSORTYPE = 'F') AND (TRASSESSOR.TRAINEEID = TRAINEE.TRAINEEID)
                        ORDER BY TRASSESSOR.ENDDATE DESC)
                        ELSE TRASSESSOR.ASSESSORID END AS [Courses/Course/MISAssessorID]
```

I'm sure its probably to do with the JOINS but I'm not qualified enough on SQL to understand what I need to do. Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: Given your example with course A. Do you want `AssessorType A` or `AssessorType E`?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using?  "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: Which dbms?  It's useless if we give solution to the wrong dbms.

Comment: I essentially want the results to output a specific assessorid for the line item dependant on the course title but im getting all the assessor id linked to the learner record

Comment: @Simon - I mean to have Course A and Course B see the edit

Comment: I added the tags for Microsoft SQL Server based on the SQL syntax in the question. If that is wrong, please change that

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - It is based on a custom DBMS that is not a common product. I believe it is based of standard sql server but I dont have 100% working knowledge as I haven't created the DBMS solution. I was hoping this would be just a sql syntax issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the issue and resolved as the Case When and select were incorrectly set. The code was essentially never running the select script to query the correct assessor